# How do I get IntelliJ worksheet to run Scala in an sbt-based project?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am doing course about scala from coursera, but i can not run my first worksheet. I created sbt scala project in Intellij 15.0.1 with SBT 0.13.8 ,java version1.7.0_85 and scala 2.11.7. Whenever i try to run my worksheet it gives me an errors:

> Error:object MacroPrinter211 is not a member of package
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.worksheet import
>   *root*.org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.worksheet.MacroPrinter211
>          ^

and the second one:

> Error:(6, 67) not found: value MacroPrinter211 println("res0: " + {val
>   $$temp$$ = inst$A$A.get$$instance$$res0;
>   MacroPrinter211.printDefInfo($$temp$$).replace("inst$A$A.", "") + " =
>   " + ( print$$$Worksheet$$$Array$$$($$temp$$)
>   ).stripPrefix("A$A12$A$A12$")})
>                                                                    ^

My code:

```
println("Hello World")
```

file structure:
test_project > src > main > scala-2.11 > hello.sc

Whenever i try to run this from terminal with sbt i get:

> [info] Set current project to scala-2-11 (in build
>   file:/home/Kuba/Codes/Scala/test_project/src/main/scala-2.11/)
>
> [error]Expected ID character
>
> [error] Not a valid command: hello (similar:
>   shell, help, reload)
>
> [error] Expected project ID
>
> [error] Expected
>   configuration
>
> [error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
>   [error] Expected key
>
> [error] Not a valid key: hello
>
> [error] hello.sc
>   [error]

However if i run this with just scala command it works perfectly.

Any idea how to fix that?

How do I get IntelliJ worksheet to run Scala in an sbt-based project?

Comment: Does the same happen in a plain Scala project without SBT?

Comment: yes. exactly the same

Comment: sounds like a bug to file on the Scala Plug-in in JetBrains YouTrack. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL

Comment: OK. Thanks guys. I actually reinstalled everything and it is working right now :)

Comment: Great.  Can you post that and accept it as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling scala plugin and updating sbt and scala it self fixed the issue.